# Testing yeoman's composeWith

Tags: unit-testing, mocha.js, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I'm trying to test generator compose scenario. In my generator I call a sub-generator if a certain prompt returns true

```
if(this.bar){
    this.composeWith('foo:bar', {});
}
```

I obviously test the bar sub-generator separately. However I would like to have an assert for this composeWith() to have been called. And I guess the problem is rather in my skills than yeoman testing docs but I have no idea how to do this. I understand that I need a spy and a stub. But the docs just list the functions and the tests for yeoman-generator itself are just mental (I tried reproducing their steps, but they mostly use dummies for everything and I only need to stub out the sub-generator).

Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I admit the documentation is lacking on this point and we could improve it.

Here's a simple example of how you could use a spy to test your sub-generator is called:

```
var generators = require('yeoman-generator').generators;
var assert = require('yeoman-generator').assert;

before(function (done) {
    this.spy = sinon.spy();
    var Dummy = generators.Base.extend({
        exec: this.spy
    });

    helpers.run('your/generator')
        .withGenerators([
            [Dummy, 'foo:bar']
        ])
        .on('end', done);
});

// Then in your assertions
it('run the sub-generator', function () {
    assert(this.spy.calledOnce);
});
```

Comment: I also had to `require('mocha-sinon')` and change `sinon.spy` to `this.sinon.spy` to have it work. There are plenty of ways to get `sinon` in scope, so OP may have a different set up.